# Angular module only works with inline javascript

Tags: javascript, angularjs, html, angularjs-scope

I am learning Angular and adding a controller to my module only works when all the code is inline on the page. If I replace it with `<script src="myModuleFile.js"></script>` it fails with

> "Error: [$injector:unpr]
>   http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.11/$injector/unpr?p0=aProvider%20%3C-%20a%20%3C-%20personController

```
var app = angular.module('app', [])
.config([function(injectables){
    console.log('configuring app');
}]).run([function(injectables){
    console.log('running app');
}]).controller("personController", function($scope){
    $scope.firstName = "John";
    $scope.lastName = "Doe";
});
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="app">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="web/stylesheets/app.css"/>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.11/angular.min.js"></script>
        <!-- wont work if I include it this way -->
        <script src="web/js/app.min.js"></script>
        <!-- but works if I put it in here -->
        <script></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <label>Name:</label>      
        <input type="text"  ng-model="yourName" placeholder="Enter a name here"><hr />      
        <h1>Hello {{ yourName }}!</h1>

        <div ng-init="firstName='John'">
            <p>The name is <span ng-bind="firstName"></span></p>
        </div>

        <p>My first expression: {{ 5 + 5 }}</p>

        <div ng-controller="personController">
            First Name: <input type="text" ng-model="firstName"><br>
            Last Name: <input type="text" ng-model="lastName"><br>
            <br>
            Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}}
        </div>


         <div ng-init="names=[
            {name:'Jani',country:'Norway'},
            {name:'Hege',country:'Sweden'},
            {name:'Kai',country:'Denmark'}]">

            <ul>
              <li ng-repeat="x in names">
                {{ x.name + ', ' + x.country }}
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>    

        <button ng-click="count = count + 1">Click me!</button>
        <p>{{ count }}</p> 
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you minifying your source? you don't seem to be using `$inject`, and don't appear to be using an array of dependencies, either.  You need some way to inject your dependencies or they will break when minified.

Comment: Are you re-initializing your module in `myModuleFile.js` since you are using `var app = angular.module('app', [])`?

Comment: BTW, have you provided us the full error message?

Comment: @claies nowhere in any of the tutorials is it indicating a controller has dependencies. A lot of the tutorials on angularJS docs don't work when they are in an external file with similar errors.

Comment: @rebornix the first code block of javascript is what is in that file. Am I missing a step? Yes that is the full message.

Comment: as you have probably discovered now (by your acceptance of the given answer), `$scope` is actually a dependency to your controller.  Unfortunately, it is common for JavaScript code to break under minification, but this is a JavaScript quirk, it's not Angular specific.  Don't let it dissuade you from using this amazing framework!

Comment: this is the first time I encountered it in the 3 years I have been using javascript. Mainly jQuery and canvas animations. AngularJS Material and Foundation Apps look really good. Cant wait t be able to do stuff with them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Claies mentioned in the comments, the error message looks like it is trying to find a provider for a dependency "a", which is probably a result of minification.

If you do like:

```
angular.module(..).controller("SomeCtrl", function($scope){});
```

It might minify `$scope` to just `a`. So instead you should use:

```
angular.module(..).controller("SomeCtrl", ["$scope", function($scope){}]);
```

Because the string will not be minified, Angular will know which dependency is which. Another way would be to use $injector of course, as Claies also mentioned.

Comment: This did the trick. I am minifying with uglify through grunt. I haven't gotten to the section on injectors yet and will probably use that once I learn it. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: No problem, you can also look at a Grunt plug in called ngAnnotate, it could do this automatically for you.